# Multiple Capybara assertions against 'page' only recognizes 'page' the first time?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, capybara

I'm trying to be diligent about my TDD and segment out any assertions when using Capybara as follows.

```
before(:all) do
  visit root_path
end

it "should have title" do
  expect(page).to have_content "ApplicationName"
end
it "should have user's name" do
  expect(page).to have_content @user.name
end
```

but the second assertion is always failing with a Capybara error

```
 Failure/Error: expect(page).to have_content "UserName001"
 Capybara::ElementNotFound:
   Unable to find xpath "/html"
```

and when I switch the order of the assertions the second is the one which always raises this error.  Does the 'page' var get cleared after the first assertion?  What is Capybara doing in this situation?  Or is this bad practice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you specified `before(:all)` you are visiting the root path only once, so only the first example is being run in the context of visiting the first page. For any subsequent tests, you haven't visited any page, so it can't find any page contents.

If you want to visit the root path before each test, change `before(:all)` to `before(:each)` or just `before`.